# Is this error about not finding a variable a scope problem?

Tags: java, scope

I am doing a parse program.this is my main file. I create an instance class of indentifier in the main file but it cant compile. error showing that inside the if statement `dataArrary.lineStart(limiterNum,lineNum);` cannot find dataArray symbol.So i did miss something ? is that a scope problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args){     
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String line = "a";  
    try{
        indentifier dataArray = new indentifier();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Discount.java"));
        Pattern a = Pattern.compile(".*for(.*)[{]");
        Pattern b = Pattern.compile(".*while(.*).*[{]");
        Pattern c = Pattern.compile(".*if(.*)[{]");
        Pattern d = Pattern.compile(".*[}]");
        Pattern e = Pattern.compile(".*class.*[{]");
        Pattern f = Pattern.compile("(.*)[{]");

        while(line != null){
            line = reader.readLine();
            Matcher mfor = a.matcher(line);
            Matcher mwhile = b.matcher(line);
            Matcher mif = c.matcher(line);
            Matcher mend = d.matcher(line);
            Matcher mclass = e.matcher(line);
            Matcher mfunc = f.matcher(line);



            if (mclass.matches() == true){
                dataArrary.lineStart(limiterNum,lineNum);
                limiteradd(0);
                continue;
            }
```

again,if i miss something on the internet. Please show me anykey word or links to point me out.thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a typo. You declare `dataArray`, but use `dataArrary`.

Comment: thank very much ,ive been looking for this problem  for few a hour dy.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `dataArrary` instead of `dataArray`. Misspell.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find `dataArrary` either, perhaps you meant `dataArray` which to declared earlier.

I tend to use my IDE's code completion to avoid such issues (and save typing)  In my IDE can can write `da` and <kbd><ctrl></kbd>+<kbd><space></kbd> and it gives me a list of possible symbols I can use.  That way I save a few key presses and its usually right.

Comment: Intellij CE (free version) its pretty good at giving you hints and quick fixes for errors in code.